# Визуализация на Python - как сделать

Tags: python, поиск-библиотек, визуализация

Задача:

> *луч выходит из центра матрицы. Найти координаты клеток, по которым проходит луч.*

Задачу решил, хочу теперь визуализировать решение, но не могу понять какими средствами (какая библиотека) это можно сделать. Идеально, если получится наложить систему координат на середину матрицы на одном графике.

Comment: Начать можно с графического отображения таблицы при помощи [pandas.plotting.table
](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html#plot-formatting) - ищите по строке: "Plotting Tables"

Comment: [tkinter](https://habr.com/ru/post/163395/) ?